# How can I web scrape multiple pages using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to collect the name and abstract of some articles. The website pages is some thing like below:

```
Page 1 (list of conferences):
  Conf1, year
  Conf2, yaer
  ....

Page 2 (list of articles for each Conf):
  Article1, title
  Article2, title
  ....

Page 2 (the page for each Article):
  Title
  Abstract
```

I would like to gather articles of each conference (with some other information about the conference like year). First, I don't know if I need to use a framework like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) for this purpose, or just write a python program. As I checked scrapy, I can have spiders like the following that can collect the conferences:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for conf in response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/main/table[1]/tbody/tr/th/a'):
            yield {
                'name': conf.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
                'link': conf.xpath('./@href').extract_first(),
            }

        for conf in response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/main/table[2]/tbody/tr/th/a'):
            yield {
                'name': conf.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
                'link': conf.xpath('./@href').extract_first(),
            }

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

However, I must follow the link for each conference to have the articles. I didn't find much examples to show me how can I collect the rest of the data I need using scrapy. Could you please guide me how to crawl the article pages when I collect data for each conference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write code like below

```
import scrapy


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for conf in response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/main/table/tbody/tr/th/a'):
            item = {'name': conf.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
                'link': response.urljoin(conf.xpath('./@href').extract_first())}

            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(conf.xpath('./@href').extract_first()), callback=self.parse_listing,
                             meta={'item': item})

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        """
        Parse the listing page urls here
        :param response:
        :return:
        """

        # Fetch listing urls Here  == > listing_urls
        # for url in listing_urls:
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        """
        Parse product details here
        :param response:
        :return:
        """

        # Fetch product details here. ==> details
        # yield details
```

Also you can view the json output like

```
scrapy crawl toscrape-xpath -o ouput.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! I also needed to process some information about each conference (like year) where can I catch and process them? how and where can I have the 'meta' attribute you set?

Comment: I used the `meta` attribute to pass some information from one function to another. If you get the year information in the main function and other information in sub-function.you can pass it via meta dictionary. Finally while yielding the data, you can fetch those specific data from meta itself.